# "I had it in the same pocket as my fishing bait"

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

Bob lost some item and when I ask for a hint, he says, "I had it in the same pocket as my fishing bait." I've checked each of the maps—where is the item?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, if the hint points to fishing/water, the item in question is found by fishing. The shadow looks like normal fish, so you just have to catch a few fish in the river/at the beach until you get the lost item.

OP image edit:

[image: looks like a normal fish]
[image: but it's a jar]